# How can I delete my meaningless post?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, vote-to-delete

I posted a meaningless question on Stack Overflow. And some guys already replied and voted it. I can't delete it. Could you please delete it for me?

[Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649619/mysql-query-error)

Comment: You can flag your own post for moderation attention asking for it to be deleted.

Comment: Why is that a meaningless post?

Comment: @Arjan, After further study I still can't find the root cause. Then I reinstalled the forum script and tried to dup this issue. But I can't dup it any more. That's why I think it's a meaningless issue now. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I wouldn't delete a question even if you've found the answer or the answer was something simple.  Other people may have the same issue and your question may help them find an answer quickly.  If, for some reason, you just don't want the question associated with you, flag it for moderator attention and ask that it be disassociated with your account.  You might also want to send email to team@stackoverflow.com if the moderator flagging doesn't work.  In accordance with the CC-Wiki license they are required to remove the association if you request it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click the `flag` link and select *Requires Moderator attention*.

Alternatively, you can also just post your own answer and accept it so that it may be still useful for someone who stumbles upon it.